# How to read two/multiple arrays nested arrays in one array and pass to chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have manged to export a nested array from a node server endpoint with some help. The code works with one array but I want to pass multiple arrays for multiple lines plotted to the chart. I thought the easiest way to do this would be to nest the array in another array? So my array looks like:

```
[[8,45,2,1],[red, green, blue, pink]]
```

Here is the html file below with my attempt to pass two arrays (This does not work)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0061)https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Line Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    <style>

@keyframes chartjs-render-animation{from{opacity:.99}to{opacity:1}}.chartjs-render-monitor{animation:chartjs-render-animation 1ms}.chartjs-size-monitor,.chartjs-size-monitor-expand,.chartjs-size-monitor-shrink{position:absolute;direction:ltr;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1}.chartjs-size-monitor-expand>div{position:absolute;width:1000000px;height:1000000px;left:0;top:0}.chartjs-size-monitor-shrink>div{position:absolute;width:200%;height:200%;left:0;top:0}</style></head>

<body>
    <script>

        const chart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'), 
    { 
        type: 'line',
        // ... 
    }
)

//const API_HOST = 'https://so-58465005-mqksg0z5tsf8.runkit.sh'
const API_HOST = 'http://localhost:3000'


fetch(`${API_HOST}/array`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => { 
        chart.config.data.labels = Array.from(Array(data[0].length)).map((_, i) => i + 1)
        chart.config.data.datasets.push({ label: 'my data0', data[0]},{label: 'my data1', data[1]})
        chart.update()
    })

    </script>
</body></html>
```

The code works ok with one array i.e `[8,45,2,1]`. How can i make it work with my nested array?

```
fetch(`${API_HOST}/array`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => { 
        chart.config.data.labels = Array.from(Array(data[0].length)).map((_, i) => i + 1)
        chart.config.data.datasets.push({ label: 'my data', data})
        chart.update()
    })

    </script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: what about flatting your array  and convert it into one array,
I mean your final array can be `[8,45,2,1red, green, blue, pink]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on [this example](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/vertical.html):

```
    var barChartData = {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            // ...
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(),
                // ...
            ]
        }, {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            // ...
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(),
                // ...
            ]
        }]
```

So basically for `datasets` you need an array with 2 elements where each contains its own data.